# Python RE: check if word is only before or after another word

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to map a variable to a specific column in excel. Let say I want to catch:

```
2.4 string
string 2.4
```

but not:

```
2.4 string 2.4
string
```

I used this expression, but that expression matches `"2.4 string 2.4"` which I do not want:

```
 r"([2]\.[4])?\s*(\"|'|inch)?\s*String\s*([2]\.[4])?\s*(\"|'|inch)?"
```

When used on a string `"2.4 string"`, the `group()` function returns only `"string"` instead of `"2.4 string"`

Anyone might know a solution?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What exactly are you trying to validate?

Comment: I want to find a cell value in excel that is either "2.4 string" or "string 2.4". I don't want the regular expression to match "2.4 string 2.4" or "string". Sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: Anyone can explain to me as to why when I apply my re above to "2.4 string" it returns "string" instead of "2.4 string" when calling .group() method? Your answer will really help my understanding. Thank you.

Comment: In my debugging tools it returns `2.4 string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:2\.4 string|string 2\.4)$
```

Sample VBScript:

```
Dim myRegExp
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "^(?:2\.4 string|string 2\.4)$"
If myRegExp.Test(SubjectString) Then
    ' Successful match
Else
    ' Match attempt failed
End If
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?: ... ) is a non-capture Group that matches...
- `2.4 string`
- OR `|`
- `string 2.4`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I used the answer you gave and it works. Thank you zx81

Comment: Thanks for the comment @as_plus_not_lose, but I realised that this was the better answer - the fact that it looks for the end of the string makes it far better than mine so I'll delete my one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(^string\s*(?:2\.4)$|^(?:2\.4)\s*string$)
```

with m, g and i flags (multiline,case insensitive and global)

This is basic regex though: it will search for

```
^string\s*(?:2\.4)$
```

OR

```
^(?:2\.4)\s*string$
```

The results in matches are "string 2.4" or "2.4 string".
Based on your provided regex I reckon you already know what each regex code inside means.
If you need further info, let me know.

Tested it on http://regex101.com/#python

EDIT: I see @zx81 already has pretty much the same answer, which is also correct

Comment: Hi trainoasis. Yes I understand basic re. Your insight on using multiline parameter is very useful. Thank you.